# php print_r not showing all values

Tags: php, arrays

For sending email via php I fill an array with the body content (easier to quick comment out something). This looks like:

```
$DeInhoud   = array();
$DeInhoud[] = "<html>";
$DeInhoud[] = "<head>";
$DeInhoud[] = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />";
$DeInhoud[] = "<title>Weborder</title>";
$DeInhoud[] = "</head>";
$DeInhoud[] = "<body>";
$DeInhoud[] = "whooohoooo";
$DeInhoud[] = "</body>";
$DeInhoud[] = "</html>";
```

When using print_r I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => whooohoooo
    [7] => 
    [8] =>  
)
```

However when feeding this array to the function mail() I do get the correct content.

What do I need to do to display the content of this array?

I tried to use the escape code \ before those < but didn't help.

Comment: Are you looking at the output in the browser? May the browser possibly be interpreting the HTML tags...?!?!?!??!!eleven

Comment: Must be tunnelvision, Tnx deceze. It does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `html` tags are getting parsed by browser as it expects the default `content-type` as `text/html`.

Set your `content-type` to plain text and try dumping the variable.

```
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
print_r($DeInhoud);
```

Comment: Tnx, will flag this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(htmlentities(implode(' ' ,$DeInhoud)));
```